# Why can't I set Windows 7 folder to Writeable?

Tags: windows-7, read-only

Moved a SATA HD from one PC to another. Copied almost all the files from old drive to new, except for one folder ("oldFolder") and it's subfolders and files.

I tried to copy just a single file (to simplify things):

Can't copy that file to same directory. (get above error)
CAN copy file to Desktop.
Can not copy files' container folder to Desktop.

Under Properties for that OldFolder:

- Read Only is Checked.
- Security:  **Everyone** set to **Allow** everything except "special permissions"
- All users are set to allow **WRITE**.

Comment: You mention "(get above error)", but you don't mention any errors above this? Did you forget to include it?

Comment: Have you attempted to claim ownership of the folder and all files and sub-folders within it? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed the problem is the folder was protected by a different windows installation and Windows respects the permissions even if they ownership is invalid for an entirely different installation.

Comment: Opps! I must have deleted the error message. That PC is now disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

goto path:

```
cd /D <path>
```

reset permission:

```
icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET
```

Comment: Tried that and now I get a warning "Do you want to copy this file without encryption"? (neither source nor destination is encrypted).I was then able to copy it from the Source to the destination drive.

Comment: @ClayNichols what write `cipher /H /S:.\ | findstr "^.E "` in `cmd` at source and destination folder?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take ownership of the folder. I'd boot to a Linux liveCD and copy all the folders/files...